# Edit suggestion rejected by Community, similar edit got accepted later

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons, specific-edit

I recently [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2371793) which was rejected by the community. Edit was on question [iOS Music app and play/pause audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269161/ios-music-app-and-play-pause-audio). I highlighted important keywords and function names for better readability, got approved by 2 users, however was rejected by community. Almost similar [edit suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17269161/revisions) for this question, by another user, got accepted.

I would like to know the reason for rejection so that I can improve my highlight edits moving forward.

Comment: The later edit is not a suggested edit nor is it accepted. It is an edit by the very user who rejected your edit. He clicked on improve and uncheck the box that says "Suggested edit was helpful".

Comment: Oh! Why does it say Community rejected, instead of the user's name?

Comment: Read the full post I have linked. You will understand it completely.

Comment: Thanks! I will go through the link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All your edit did was `code "highlight"` some of the terms like `iPhone 5`, which were not `code` and so should not be `"highlighted"` in this way. However, actual code snippets like `audioPlayerEndInterruption:withOptions:` **are** `code`, so code formatting is appropriate.

Your edit doesn't address any of the following problems with the question:

- it's one wall of text and difficult to read
- it's not clear which part the actual question is
- spelling, e.g. interrutions
- there's a "thanks in advance" at the end

so was correctly labelled "not helpful".

The fact that two people approved it is a poor show on their part.

Comment: My edit did include code highlight along with keywords for iOS versions and device's that OP mentioned. I do agree with you on points #3 and #4, which were not addressed in my edit.

Comment: @Amar However keywords for devices/versions are not code... the actual code highlighting was good (the one part which the other editor used).

Comment: Thanks for the concise info. I found it useful.