# Question edit was attributed to another user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I suggested an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19238753/adding-sql-indices) a few minutes ago. I edited the title, some spelling mistakes and the formatting of a posted SQL structure.

After a few minutes an edit was accepted which seemed exactly like mine, but to my surprise it is attributed to another user (FerretallicA). I also didn't get any points for my edit.

Looking at the Suggested edits history I found that my suggested edit approved/ rejected and then edited:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3086162

But finally it is approved more or less in its original form: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19238753/revisions

Is this a bug? It definitively seems very unfair that the edit and points were attributed to another user.

**UPDATE**
Looking at the revision history, the reject on my suggested edit was done by `Community`, which is as far as I understand, a bot. Could this have cause a misbehavior of the approval system?

*These two question seems similar, but differ in one way or another*

[Why did this edit get attributed to the community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193038/why-did-this-edit-get-attributed-to-the-community-user)

[My suggested edit and author's edit were merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177371/my-suggested-edit-and-authors-edit-were-merged)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suggested edit was **not** approved. Looking at the [suggested edit review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3086162) a reviewer edited the post while reviewing and un-selected '*Suggested edit was helpful*' so the community rejected your edit.

> [image]

---

For you update: [See Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/187824)

Comment: If you look at the edit done by FerretallicA and my answer, you will find they are identical, except for a few insignificant characters. I still claim this is unjust.

Comment: @ile - Read my answer again. If a review select an option *improve* while reviewing that means he is improving your edit. So it looks identical.

Comment: Thank you for the referenced link, I will study it in a moment. Meanwhile - the "improving" of my suggested edit (after being reject) was to change **Also, here's the structure of the tables:** into **The structure of the tables:`** In my opinion, given the other more important edits, they ARE identical and this is a way for abusing the review system in cases when Community automatically rejects an edit. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ile - If the reviewer find the suggested edit is minor and there were other things to edit on the post, they can un-select *'Suggested edit was helpful'* option while improving the suggested edit. But it is totally depends on the reviewer. In this case I would have approve your edit since you did almost everything you should including edit summery.

Comment: Understood. This is very discouraging however, the end result is that the credit for a reviewer's efforts go to another. It would have been useful to be able to report such issues and ask for moderator attention (analogical to the flag feature).

Comment: @ile - In future if the reviewer(s) reject your suggested edit and you think the edit was appropriate, you can ask here by adding full details including the reason why your edit was valid. And keep in mind [voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) :)

Answer (score 2):

On checking the [question's suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19238753/revisions) edits it seems another user has added more information along with your edits. Since that user ([with more privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))tried to improve your answer ans hence it turned to him.

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19238753/revisions, your suggestion has been REJECTED by community.

Comment: The other user's edit was to change `Also, here's the structure of the tables:` to `The structure of the tables:`. The more important edits were untouched and the edit was then posted under the other user. I still think this is a wrong.

Comment: @ile I don't think it has bug.  However sometimes happens which is fully depends on the reviewer.  Since the user has the privilege to [Edit Questions And Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) it has been moved on to his name.  Also take a look at this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185599/edit-suggestion-rejected-by-community-similar-edit-got-accepted-later

Comment: oops, @user1671639 - that's the exact same question, thanks. On a side note, I understand but I still feel frustrated that for spending 10 minutes editing a post I got auto-rejected and another user gets credit as a result.

Comment: @ile You don't need to get frustrated, As I already mentioned the user with 2000rep does not get any rep for editing other posts. FYI:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit.  Actually both the edits are invalid according to community, since the user had (2000+ rep) this will not come under REVIEW category(will be placed directly).  Hope you understand.  Continue your GOOD WORK and make STACK EXCHANGE a better site.  Good luck.